# static reference to the non-static method

Tags: android, reference, static, non-static

At saveImage(), first line said :

```
" Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method  getDrawingCache() 
from the type View "
```

How can I fix that ?

```
public class ButtonDraw extends Activity {

    public Canvas myCanvas;
    private BlackPixel blackPixel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.paintingfile);


          blackPixel = new BlackPixel(this);
          setContentView(blackPixel);
          blackPixel.requestFocus();



    } 
       public void saveImage()
        {
          Bitmap bitmap = BlackPixel.getDrawingCache();   //

            try 
                {

                    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("name.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, fos);

                    fos.close();                            
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

      }

}



public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        switch(item.getItemId())
        {

        case R.id.menu_paintingfileToast:
            saveImage();
            Toast mToast=Toast.makeText(ButtonDraw.this, "Save Succesfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            mToast.show();

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: `how can i fix that`, dont make a reference to a static method in a non-static method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the class `BlackPixel` instead of your field `blackPixel`.

Simply write `blackPixel` with a lower case b in that line.

Comment: You're welcome, make sure to select an answer once your problem is solved.

Comment: Do you have any ideea where it save the image on the phone ? The exactly folder ? :  FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("name.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: and how should i select the answer ?

Comment: @user3002074 on the left side there is a small checkmark next to the answer that you can click. That's how you select an answer. No I don't know about the location of the image, you would have to open another question for that. :)